# Pandas: sort/percentile each row within column categories

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe, percentile

I was wondering if there is an eloquent way to sort (calculate percentile) across columns in a Pandas dataframe with the following condition:

Do the percentile calculation within each category. Each column will belong to a category and the percentile calculation to be done within each category (please see the link for a graphical description.)

I learned that I can do the following which will disregard the categories:

```
TargetRanking = StartingData.rank(axis="columns", pct=True)
```

But I would need to groupby each row by the category of each column. Please see the graphical description at the following link.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you had a dict with the category mappings, you could simply group the columns by that dict and then use [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) as previously.

```
categories = {'X1': 'A', 'X3': 'A', 'X5': 'A', 'X2': 'B', 'X4': 'B'}

df.set_index('Date').groupby(categories, axis=1).rank(pct=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi... This code used to work great until recently. In pandas '0.23.0' I am getting an error when running this sample code:    d = dict()
d ={'A': 'Health Care', 'AA': 'Materials', 'B': 'Health Care', 'BB': 'Materials'}
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,4), index=range(0,100), columns=d.keys() )
data.groupby(d , axis = "columns").rank(axis = "columns", pct=True)                                      the error is:   ValueError: Shape of passed values is (100, 4), indices imply (100, 100)